# Rendering Whitespace in Rails input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Assuming a user inputs the following...

> This is a dummy  text that may
>
> have some           random
>
> whitespaces wherever  in the body

How do I accept this in a rails form and output this from an instance variable?

**EDIT**: Stackoverflow's Markdown did not render the text I typed in properly either. The originsl text - assuming underscores are spaces will be input as such:

> This`_`is`_`a`_`dummy`____`text`_`that`_`may
>   `_`
>   `_`
>   have`_`some`____________________`random
>   `_`
>   `_`
>   `_`
>   whitespaces`_`wherever`__`in`_`the`_`body

I tried the usual rails scaffold methods: `= f.text_area :message` in the form and `= @user.message` to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `textarea` tag for that. In rails it would translate to something like:
`<%= f.text_area :notes %>`
where f is the form handle.

If you want to store it in mysql, use a `text` datatype.